# how to bind values to single spinner from one web service, another default value in android

Tags: android

```
String[] s={"1","2","3","4"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,s);
spin.setAdapter(adp);
```

Now I want to get "4" at zero position of Spinner.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't change the position of the items inside a `Spinner` after you have set its `Adapter`.

If you want 4 to be the first item, you have to order your list accordingly:

```
String[] s={"4","1","2","3"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, s);
spin.setAdapter(adp);
```